# Two fragments in place of one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the necessity to replace one starting fragment (I'll call it A) of an activity with two other fragments (B and C, in the "usual" list+viewer configuration). Currently I have a relative layout with two frame layouts acting as a placeholder for B and C:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup_navigation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <!-- Some radiobuttons (not displayed for the sake of brevity) -->
    </RadioGroup>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_list"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/radiogroup_navigation">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/radiogroup_navigation"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/frame_list">
 </FrameLayout>
```

When I need to display A, I just hide **frame_list** and add A to **frame_view**, and when I need to display B and C I set **frame_list visible** again and add the two fragments to each frame, in the same fragment transaction.

```
FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
t.remove(fragmentA);
t.add(R.id.frame_list, fragmentB);
t.add(R.id.frame_view, fragmentC);
t.addToBackStack(null);
t.commit();
```

In this way, when i press the back button, both C and B go away and I'm back to A fragment, but now **frame_list** is visible (and empty).

I am thinking to solve the problem in two possible ways:

- overriding onBackPressed to hide the left frame if needed;
- nesting B and C in another fragment;

But I also feel I'm probably looking at the problem in the wrong way, and maybe there's a cleaner design solution. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here is one solution:

1. Create two activities ActivityA and ActivityBC
2. Create another fragment with the radiogroup
3. Embed FragmentRadio into both ActivityA and ActivityBC
4. Have that fragment start new activities based on selection whilst finishing current activity

Answer (score 0):

Make fields like this:

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_B_TAG = "fragmentB";
```

When you add the fragments, use the static `String`s like tags:

```
t.add(R.id.frame_list, fragmentB, FRAGMENT_B_TAG);
t.add(R.id.frame_view, fragmentC, FRAGMENT_C_TAG);
```

In your activity, set up a listener, which will get triggered every time after you call `addToBackStack(String)`. It will find out which fragment is currently visible and hide/show needed containers.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        FragmentA fa = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_A_TAG);
        FragmentB fb = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_B_TAG);
        if (fa != null && fa.isVisible()) {
            // Fragment A is visible, so hide the second container which is now empty
        }
        if (fb != null && fb.isVisible()) {
            // Fragment B is visible, so show the second container
        }
    }
});
```

Notice that checking whether `Fragment C` is visible or not is not needed since when `Fragment B` is visible, `Fragment C` is always visible too.

This is an untested code, but I think it should work. Also, if you need any explanation, don't hesitate to ask.

Hope it helps.